# why gdb cannot work good on detach thread?

Tags: c++, gdb

I use gdb to debug my program, but I found it doesn't work good on detach thread, code show as below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

void fn()throw(){
            int i = 0;
                    string str("aaa");
}

void fn2(){
            fn();

}

int main(){
    thread th(fn2);
    th.detach(); //set thread to detach
    return 0;
}
```

compile and debug it

```
g++ main.cpp -O0 -std=c++11 -pthread
gdb a.out
```

In gdb, I set breakpoints at fn and fn2 then execute run, but not trigger any breakpoints

```
(gdb) b fn
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400d86
(gdb) b fn2
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400e0a
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/project/test/a.out 
warning: File "/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
        add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
        set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
        info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff6ef6700 (LWP 9583)]
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
(gdb) Cannot find user-level thread for LWP 9583: generic error
(gdb) [Thread 0x7ffff6ef6700 (LWP 9583) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 9559) exited normally]
```

what if I replace `th.detach()` with `th.join` that all  breakpoints will be triggered normally, why?

Comment: Because the program exits before you reach any of the breakpoints.

Comment: What version of gdb are you using? Mine is 8.1 on Ubuntu and I don't see "Couldn't get registers: No such process" or "generic error" messages (breakpoints are not triggered but they don't need to be, as explained in the comment above). And why are you running as root? This is not very secure.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1,  g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609,  and system is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS \n \l

Comment: Well that's ancient. gdb is improving all the time.